# how to show faces of people who are attending event created by my application using facebook api?

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am developing an application of create event in facebook  . It has a regiatration page when a user creates event he can sell or buy ticket .the question is how can i show facess of people who are attending the event created by my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got the facebook ids ($uid) of the people who are attending to your event, you can show their face with a img tag with the  href from this quick function:

```
public function getPicture($uid, $size) {
    return "https://graph.facebook.com/".$uid."/picture?type=".$size;
}
```

There is several sizes :

- square (50x50)
- small (50 pixels wide, variable height)
- normal (100 pixels wide, variable height)
- large (about 200 pixels wide, variable height)

see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: sir  i dont have the facebook ids of people attending the event.can u tell me how to fetch the facebook id s of attendes jmeyo

Answer (score 3):

To get the users who are attending, you need to call the "`attending`" connection of the [`event`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) object:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/attending?access_token=XXXXXXXXX
```

Then you could use the approach mentioned by @jmeyo.